# WPF: how to define collections for use in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, collections

I want to define something like this

```
<myCustomControl>
  <myCustomControl.Images>
     <Image
        Source="{StaticResource LockedIcon16}" />
     <Image
        Source="{StaticResource UnlockedIcon16}"/>
  <myCustomControl.Images>
<myCustomControl/>
```

what property definitions do i need to get that collection (Images) happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.Windows.Controls.Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) should do it.

Haven't tested it, but it should work.

```
public class myCustomControl {
  //...
    public ObservableCollection<Image> Images {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Image>)GetValue(ImagesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImagesProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Images.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImagesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Images", typeof(ObservableCollection<Image>), typeof(myCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Comment: Just an Image, or do you mean an *array* or *List* (IEnumerable) of Image?

Comment: `List<Image>` is the easiest to do. Haven't tried with arrays, not sure if it'll work.

Comment: i was wrong about this, it doesnt have to be a dependency property, the collection just has to be instantiated before use

Comment: It seems the collection has to be an ObservableCollection<>; certainly, List<> won't work (with List<> it tries to assign to the collection variable rather than adding to the collection).

Comment: @BobSammers, I used IList only, the only requirement is to initialize it otherwise it throughs Exception.
Also if there is a need of Binding then only go for dependency property otherwise Images can be CLR Property.